# Angular developers need a path to call for the content from aem page

Tags: aem

I generated the json file and gave the path /bin/***/filename.json . I am able to see the json file in author mode but not in publish. Our aem ops team says they cannot make bin as public. Tried to change the path, using js generated the json path file now at path /content/***/***/filename.json which I am able to see in author mode but not in publish.

My question is is there any other way that I can try . Please if any other ideas do comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a dispatcher?  Does the dispatcher config allow the URL pattern you are trying to reach?

Comment: access to `*.json` extension is disabled by default in the dispatcher, you'll have to explicitly allow your specific path in `dispatcher.any`

Comment: Please provide more information what type of error you receive on publisher. 404, 403, 500 etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Or just simple: Angular get content of page by call .infinity.json
Examp:

Your page is: /mysite/en/home.html

We change to : /mysite/en/home.infinity.json

For more detail: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2337725

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

We open using `url` under `/bin/..` for `SlingServlet`

First create a `slingSevlet`

```
@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/filename.json", methods = "GET", metatype=true)
```

Then check the filter and make sure that `/bin/filename.json` accepts GET requests:

1. `curl 'http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr'`
2. Search for 'Apache Sling Referrer Filter'
3. Check the configuration